# python move files from macos file system to shared windows server

Tags: python, macos, shutil

I have a problem moving my mac local files to a shared windows server location.
It deletes the file in source but none has been moved to destination.
I've got no error and my code is as simple as this. Any ideas?

```
def moveCSVtoClientFolder():
    dest = "\\MyServer\Destination\"
    shutil.copy(csvfile, dest+ csvfile)
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: The first backslash is escaping the second one, leaving you with only one backslash at the beginning of the destination.

Comment: Also, that can't be the code you're running, as it has a syntax error.  You can't end a string with `\"`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @John-Gordon .You are right I had removed the real path, It doesn't have a backslash in the end, I tried this as well. still no luck. shutil.copy("test.csv", "\\MyServer\Destination")

Comment: If I run the py file in the server it works just fine, But, If I try to run it from my Mac it will do nothing

Comment: I'm not sure it will helps... but try to change backslash to slash: `dest = "//MyServer/Destination/"`

Comment: Got it fixed when I mounted the destination paths and used Volumes/MyServer/Destination, Thanks John and Viktor for your answers